# how get last 10 transaction hash for a address (kotlin)

Tags: transactions, hash

i want to get last 10 transaction hash of a wallet address.
i use block numbers but it's return block number is too wide !
the block number is limited and every hrs is under update....
if anyone know a way please help me.

Comment: You can use web3 APIs like Moralis to get this data. They index the blockchain data and you can query the data using their API endpoints. The response from this API is ordered from new blocks to old blocks. So if you limit the response to 10 transaction you get the latest 10 transactions of the wallet. 
https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-decoded-wallet-transaction